# Override function from File.php

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

I'm trying to override the `_validateUploadedFile()` method from the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_File` located in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php`

This is my `config.xml` located in `app/code/local/Eps/Customizationurl/etc`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eps_Customizationurl>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Eps_Customizationurl>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <epscustomizationurl>
                <class>Eps_Customizationurl_Model</class>
            </epscustomizationurl>
            <customfile>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_option_type_file>Eps_Customizationurl_Model_Product_Option_Type_File</product_option_type_file>
                </rewrite>
            </customfile>
        </models>    
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <!-- Event fired when converting from a quote item (items in cart) to order item, this
             happens when checking out orders -->
            <sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
                <observers>
                    <eps_customizationurl_model_observer>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>epscustomizationurl/observer</class>
                        <method>epsURLCreator</method>
                    </eps_customizationurl_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

And this is the `File.php` file located in `app/code/local/Eps/Customizationurl/Model/Product/Option/Type`:

```
<?php 
class Eps_Customizationurl_Model_Product_Option_Type_File extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_File {

    protected function _validateUploadedFile() {
        Mage::log('Starting custom _validateUploadedFile()!', null, 'system.log', true);
    }

}
?>
```

The class `Eps_Customizationurl_Model` inside an `Observer.php` is working perfectly but I can't manage to overwrite the method from `File.php`. It keeps running the default code, not the code I'm overriding it with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because you are using a group of `customfile`
This is not ambiguous this is what tells it what model you are overwriting.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eps_Customizationurl>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Eps_Customizationurl>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <epscustomizationurl>
                <class>Eps_Customizationurl_Model</class>
            </epscustomizationurl>
            <catalog> // This needs to match the model tag from the module you are overwriting
                <rewrite>
                    <product_option_type_file>Eps_Customizationurl_Model_Product_Option_Type_File</product_option_type_file>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>    
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <!-- Event fired when converting from a quote item (items in cart) to order item, this
             happens when checking out orders -->
            <sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
                <observers>
                    <eps_customizationurl_model_observer>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>epscustomizationurl/observer</class>
                        <method>epsURLCreator</method>
                    </eps_customizationurl_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```